# onItemSelectedListener Not working on spinner Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I´m using kotlin and I'm tryng to do something with the itoms that select from my spinner. I'm using this code that I get from another similar question, but is not working at all. Anyone knows why? or what I'm missing?

```
spinnerBooks.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerBooksArray!!)
spinnerBooks.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        val text = parent!!.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
        Toast.makeText(this@AddAuction,"SELECTED: $text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening. There's an "empty" toast or any toast at all?

Comment: There is No toast at all